# core animation error

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I was messing around with Core Animation trying to get it to work, and I'm fairly sure I did everything right but when I tried to run my program Xcode threw up these bizarre errors at me:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CALayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CABasicAnimation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I have no idea what any of that means. I imported the QuartzCore framework into the appropriate view controller, and here is the code I used for the animation:

```
UIImage *image01 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image01];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(455, 150, 150, 150);

CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageLayer.bounds = imageView.frame;
imageLayer.contents = imageView;
[view.layer addSublayer:imageLayer];

CGFloat imageXAtStart = imageLayer.position.x;
imageLayer.position = CGPointMake(335, 150);

CABasicAnimation *imageAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
imageAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:imageXAtStart];
imageAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:335];
imageAnimation.duration = 3;
imageAnimation.beginTime = 2;
[imageLayer addAnimation:imageAnimation forKey:@"position"];
```

If it matters, the animation is just supposed to move the image/layer from one x value to another.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This means you haven't linked your application to the framework which implements those classes.

Mind that linking is not the same as importing. By importing the header files you let the compiler know that the classes exist. By linking to the framework you point the compiler the implementation of the classes themselves.

Right click your Frameworks directory (or any directory) in Xcode and select *Add existing framework*. Now choose the appropriate framework and click *Choose*.

**PS:** George is right, do something about your accept rate. You've asked five or so questions but haven't accepted one answer. If you continue like this, eventually nobody will want to answer your questions anymore.

Comment: perfect, that did the trick, thank you! although in xcode 4 it was a little more difficult, you can't just right-click on the directory anymore to add a framework. you have to click the project target, go to the build phases tab, click the "Link Binary with Libraries" option, and there's a little + that allows you to add a framework.

Comment: To add a framework in xcode 4, (1) right click on a framework already within the project (from the project navigator) (2) choose "show in finder" (3) locate the framework you'd like to add in the finder window and (4) drag it into the frameworks folder.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, It was only to add the framework in the project:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

everybody could see that something is not included.
It is obvious you have to include a framework.
Advising to include a framework without saying which one is kinda lame.
Choose what ?

Comment: No problem. I knew what framework they were talking about because I'd imported it, I just hadn't added it to the project, and it didn't occur to me to say what it was before. I'll make sure to be better about that in the future.